# Cropping of OV2640 full resolution, understanding the registers

Tags: camera

I'm working with a k210 chip on a sipeed maix go, and I'm trying to process UXGA pictures. The chip can't handle having more than QVGA pictures in memory, so I want to only retrieve a "crop" of the full resolution at a time.

To do so, I'm trying to use the registers described in the [datasheet](https://www.uctronics.com/download/cam_module/OV2640DS.pdf).
The thing is I don't understand how the registers relate to each other, and I'm getting a lot of "sensor timeouts", "green images" and other things of the sort.

I've identified the following registers as being relevant: HSIZE, VSIZE, XOFFL, YOFFL, VHYX, TEST, ZMOW, ZMOH, ZMHH, SIZEL, HSIZE8, VSIZE8, COM1, COM7, HREFST, HREFEND, VSTRT, VEND and REG32.

Can someone help me understand how this registers work and how to use them to achieve the desired objective?

---

The maix go is a bit more complex than the camera, It has it's own "firmware". There are 3 alternatives for the firmware, which can be found here: [github.com/sipeed](https://github.com/sipeed). Two are C and one is a micropython implementation(MaixPy). I'm trying to modify MaixPy's source code ov2640 interface implementation. I've tried using windowing but I think I must change the other registers in order for it to work. The interface is here: [ov2640.c](https://github.com/sipeed/MaixPy/blob/91f5b3b3b7b512bac1d5ace5a797413c01484926/components/micropython/port/src/omv/ov2640.c). I'm messing with "svga_config".

Also, here are

- maixpy's docs: [maixpy.sipeed.com](https://maixpy.sipeed.com/en/)
- k210 page: [kendryte.com](https://kendryte.com/)
- And sipeed maix go page: [seeedstudio.com](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Sipeed-MAix-GO-Suit-for-RISC-V-AI-IoT-p-2874.html).

Basically, sipeed took the chip and put it into "usable" boards.

Comment: Do you have a data sheet for the chipset used by the OV2640? Have you tried to use windowing?

Comment: @Andyaka I have tried using window. I don't understand what you mean by chipset, the maix go board?
 I'm not really used to working with electronics and with low level code, I'm more used to java/python type of code, but I do know how to program in C.

Comment: Well, you asked about the registers i.e. you wanted to know how they work and how to use them so, me being a hardware guy I asked if you had details about the chipsets.

Comment: @Andyaka thank you so much for your replies. The only documentations that I know are the ones I linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I ended up figuring out the solution to my problem.
HSIZE and VSIZE should be set to the same as the window size(HREFST, HREFEND, VSRT, VEND, ...), divided by 4. OFFSETS set to zero. HSIZE8 and VSIZE8 should be set to specific values for uxga (look up interface implementations to see what those values are). COM7 should be set to UXGA 0x00. The window size and positioning is how you get the crops.
And finally, the part that actually had me scratching my head, for some reason auto exposure doesn't work when setting to UXGA and using these crops. So, you have to set REG45 and AEC manually, and set exposure level to manual (COM8).